# Use "which" to find path of first argument in Bash not working

Tags: bash

I've been working on a small script that opens gedit or whatever editor I have in my Linux box to edit another script that is in a folder that is included in the `PATH` variable.

I am using `which` to find the path of the script so that I can give the path to the editor and start editing that script. The name of the script is obviously the first argument of the script.

The problem is that `which` cannot find the script when it is given as the first argument of another script, but it will find the path if I use it directly.

Here is an example to make it clearer.

```
which script.sh
prints "/home/bla/bla/script_folder/script.sh
```

but if I use that in a script like so:

```
echo "ScriptPath: $(which 1)"
echo "ScriptName: $1"
```

This won't work for some weird reason. I do know the location for the script used in argument 1 is available in my PATH variable. `Echo` will not print anything when I give it `$(which 1)`, assuming `$1` is the name of the script I am looking for. I have no idea why this is. Then I decided to put the name of the script in a variable and then use which to find whatever that new variable contains (in my case the name of the script), but it won't work either.

**Ex:**

```
scriptName="$1"
echo "$(which scriptName)"
This won't work either.
Such a simple thing, and I cannot make it work for some weird reason. Any ideas why this is not working?
```

Comment: You seem to be dropping dollar signs inside `$()` -- you need `$(which "$1")` and `$(which "$scriptName")`. Only in *arithmetic* evaluation you can drop the sigil: `x=5; echo $((x+1))`

Answer (score 1):

As @glenn jackman commented: you need to use `$` to reference variables, even inside `$( )`. Thus, the command  `echo "ScriptPath: $(which 1)"` looks for a command named "1". What you want is `echo "ScriptPath: $(which "$1")"` (note that wrapping variable references like `$1` in double-quotes is almost always a good idea). Similarly:

```
scriptName="$1"
echo "$(which scriptName)" # doesn't work, looks for a command named "scriptName"
echo "$(which "$scriptName")" # works as expected
```

Comment: Thanks man, I am used to use $(which cmd) that I totally didn't catch that. Must be really tired :s thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have it wrong with $(which 1)
where you need to put the command that you want to run inside backticks: `which $1`

```
echo "Script Path: `which $1`"
echo "Script Name: $1"
```

Comment: You totally right, I must be really tired for not catching that :S. Thanks guys